# Chrome: How to insert two consecutive spans into editable body without nesting them

Tags: javascript, range

I am trying to insert two consecutive spans into an editable body element on Chrome.  My problem is that the 2nd span is ending up inside the first span instead of next to it.

I have simplified my example, but in real life, the end user might have moved the cursor or selected some text in between the two inserts.

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function load(){
    insert("<span style='color:red'>hello</span>");
    insert("<span>goodbye</span>");
}

function insert(sHtml){

    var oSel = window.getSelection();
    var oRange = oSel.rangeCount > 0 ? oSel.getRangeAt(0) : void 0;

    if(!oRange){
        oRange = window.document.createRange();
        oRange.selectNodeContents(window.document.body);
    }

    var newFrag = oRange.createContextualFragment(sHtml);
    oRange.insertNode(newFrag);
    oRange.collapse(false);
    oSel.removeAllRanges()
    oSel.addRange(oRange);

}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="load()">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Especially when there is no window.selection onload of a pag

Answer (score 3):

You're doing strange and complex things to insert your nodes. Why using the selection ?

Using jquery, you could define your insert function like this :

```
function insert(html) {
   $("body").append(html);
}
```

Without jquery, you would have to add the node and set a text in the node :

```
var newNode = document.createElement("span");
newNode.setAttribute("style", "color:red");
newNode.appendChild(document.createTextNode("hello"));
document.body.append(newNode);
```

Comment: Sorry.  I tried to simplify the code to make the problem clearer and removed too much context.  In real life, the body is editable and the user might have moved the cursor or selected some text in between the two inserts.